# Check if XML Schema is correctly converted from a DTD

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd, xsd-validation

I've an exercise which asks me to translate a DTD into an XML Schema. I know that it's possibile to validate a XML document in respect to a DTD (I'm using xml developer by oxygen). Is it possibile to validate a XML Schema respect to a DTD? I'm asking this because I'd like to check if my translation is correct.

This is my DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE x [
<!ELEMENT x (y1,y2)+>
<!ELEMENT y1 ((z1|z2)*,(z3,z4)+)>
<!ELEMENT y2 (z1?,z2*,z3?)>
<!ELEMENT z1 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT z2 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT z3 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT z4 EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST x attrx CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST y1 attry CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

This is my XML schema attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="x" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="tipox">
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="y1" type="tipoy1"/>
            <xsd:element name="y2" type="tipoy2"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="attrx" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="tipoy1">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="z1" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="z2" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="z3" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="z4"><xsd:complexType/></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="attry" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="tipoy2">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="z1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="z2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="z3" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be some differences between the translations made either manually or using tools for example <!ELEMENT z1 (#PCDATA)> can be interpreted as

```
<xsd:element name="z1">
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true"/>
</xsd:element>
```

or simply

```
<xsd:element name="z1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
```

Instead of translating manually, you could better rely on translators like 
[XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) and then customize to your needs by narrowing down scopes, occurrences and your elements/complexType usage preferences.